# What noise is this coming from our ice machine?

Tags: appliances, ice-maker

We have a Scotsman NU130 ice machine that's become quite noise lately.

Here's a video of the noise: https://youtube.com/shorts/3UFw4yjXxtQ

When it comes to ice makers, is there a particular part that I should focus in on replacing or fixing to address the noise?

Comment: Probably lots of ice build up. Clean it

Answer (score 1):

Ice makers tend to ice over and block the gears.

Yours sound like stuck motor.

Clean the Ice build up.